# error: parse error on input ‘divideMediaR'’

Tags: haskell

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Haskell donde debo calcular el par (ys,zs) , donde ys contiene los elementos de xs estrictamente menores que la media, mientras que zs contiene los elementos de xs estrictamente mayores que la media. Necesito hacerlo por filtrado, por compresión y por recursión, y tengo problemas con este último (divideMediaR)

```
main = print(divideMediaF[6, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 4], divideMediaC[1, 2, 3], divideMediaR[1, 2, 3])

media :: [Double] -> Double
media xs = (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)

divideMediaF :: [Double] -> ([Double], [Double])
divideMediaF xs = (filter (<m) xs, filter (>m) xs) where m = media xs

divideMediaC :: [Double] -> ([Double], [Double])
divideMediaC xs = ([x | x <- xs, x < m], [x | x <- xs, x > m]) where m = media xs

divideMediaR :: [Double] -> ([Double], [Double])
divideMediaR xs = divideMediaR' xs 
    where m = media xs
        divideMediaR' [] = ([], [])
        divideMediaR' (x:xs) 
        | x < m = (x:ys, zs) 
        | x == m = (ys, zs) 
        | x > m = (ys, x:zs) 
        where (ys, zs) = divideMediaR' xs
```

No tengo idea del por qué me salta este error, y llevo un buen rato intentando buscar soluciones sin resultado alguno.

Comment: Hola DanielBeltranS2, bienvenido, estás en Soes, el idioma oficial es el español, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la traduzcas, para obtener un mejor recibimiento y evitar recibir votos negativos, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 1):

Olvídenlo, ya lo resolví. Resulta que había que indentar una parte del código para que quedara resuelto el problema.

```
divideMediaR :: [Double] -> ([Double],[Double])
divideMediaR xs = divideMediaR' xs 
    where 
        m = media xs
        divideMediaR' [] = ([],[])
        divideMediaR' (x:xs) | x < m = (x:ys, zs)
            | x == m = (ys, zs)
            | x > m = (ys, x:zs) where (ys, zs) = divideMediaR' xs
```